# mysql database update using webservices

Tags: mysql, exception, model-view-controller, dao

I am using mysql database and workbench, Eclipse IDE, and Tomcat server.
I am using MVC model for web services. In HTML form when i supply the username and password, all the details of the user are displayed and when i try to update details for that user it is allowing me to change the details on the webpage. but when i submit the updated details form, then it is showing the below exception and the details are not updated in the database.

## Header 1

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Sapan' in 'where clause'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at com.dao.CustomerDAO.updateProduct(CustomerDAO.java:145)
at com.dao.UpdateServlet.doPost(UpdateServlet.java:81)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680
```

I don't where is the issue, but when i try to retrieve the data first it is coming with out any error. and also there is an username 'Sapan' is present in my database. The method that is to update the database is here.

### Header 2

public class CustomerDAO extends BaseDAO{

```
public boolean updateProduct(Login login){
    try {
    BaseDAO baseDAO = new BaseDAO();
    Connection c = baseDAO.getConnection();
    String query = "update test.Customer set City=? ,State=? ,PhoneNumber=? ,Email=? ,Address=? ,ZipCode=? where LoginId="+login.getLoginId();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, login.getCity());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, login.getState());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, login.getCellnumber());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, login.getEmail());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, login.getAddress());
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, login.getZipcode());
    int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.println("Record updated successfully.");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return true;
```

}
}

Please help me to fing out where is the issue.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly states `Unknown Column`. It's not saying there's no matching record. That is **NOT** an error that would throw a full-blown stack backtrace. That's simply an empty result set, and is a perfectly valid result.

The problem is that you're performing an SQL injection attack on yourself. You properly use placeholders for all of the fields, **EXCEPT** the actual username. Since you haven't used placeholders, **AND** failed to quote that value, you've created an SQL syntax error:

```
... where LoginId="+login.getLoginId();
```

should be

```
... where LoginId='" + login.getLoginId()  + "'";
                  ^--missing              ^^^^^^--missing in your code
```

to correct the immediate error. And better yet, should be

```
... where LoginID=?

preparedStatement.setInt(7, login.getLoginID());
```

Your query, as generated by your code, is coming out as

```
... where LoginID=Sapan
```

without the quotes, `Sapan` is interpreted as a field name, which doesn't exist, hence your error.